# Question regarding the "Disciplined" badge and deleting my own answer

Tags: support, badges

The "Disciplined" badge is earned when you delete your own post with a score of 3 or higher.  When I hover over the "delete" link on one of my answers, it says "vote to remove this post".  In order to delete one of my own answers, does it need to be voted on?  Or will it just be deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that saying "vote to remove post" is not very clear.  It doesn't seem like a vote to me, just saying "delete this answer" would make more sense.  Maybe this should be an enhance request.